# Bootstrap Date picker and moment.js jalali calendar

Tags: momentjs, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, persian-calendar, jalali-calendar

I'm using bootstrap [datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) in my project.
I need to change it to jalali calendar, so:

1. I used `locale:'fa'` in datetimepicker initializing code
2. I added `moment-jalaali.js` after `moment.js`

So after adding [`moment-jalaali`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/jalaali/) when I click on textbox datetimepicker doesn't appear.

I placed here my source code, and I hope you can help me to solve this issue.
http://www.bshafiei.ir/uploader/files/DatePickers.zip

Comment: I fear that the datetimepicker you are using does not support jalaali calendar.

Answer (score -2):

Here you can find a cool opensource Jalali calendar based on bootstrap

https://github.com/rafihaidari/Jalali-Calendar-and-Datepicker